# lodash debounce function not executing the input function which is provided as argument in debounce

Tags: react-native, lodash, expo, react-native-elements

the lodash debounce function not executing the input function.

```
<Slider
    value={this.state.slider}
    onValueChange={(slider) => { _.debounce(() => {
      console.log(this.state.slider)
      this.setState({ slider })
      }, 20)}}
/>
```

the value of slider is not changing as well as the not printing the console.log value it means that the debounce input function is not executing.
please tell what is error.

Comment: please answer someone??